# Different results for exit conditions in process call

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

As a small part of a project, I'm calling ffmpeg to convert a video - I worked from an old example that used some of the output to create a progress bar, which was hanging. Code below:

```
[initiation code common to both examples]
    Dim inputFile, outputFile As String, myProcess As New Process
    Dim psiProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo, ffreader As StreamReader


    inputFile = "C:\Users\mklefass\Downloads\Video 2017-08-16 21.01.39.mov"
    outputFile = "C:\Users\mklefass\Downloads\tmp2\Output"

    psiProcInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\ffmpeg.exe"  'Location Of FFMPEG.EXE
    psiProcInfo.Arguments = " -i " & Chr(34) & inputFile & Chr(34) & " -vf fps=5 " & Chr(34) & outputFile & "%d.jpg" & Chr(34)                              'start ffmpeg with command strFFCMD string
    psiProcInfo.UseShellExecute = False                             'use the shell execute command we always want no
    psiProcInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden             'hide the ffmpeg process window
    psiProcInfo.RedirectStandardError = True                        'Redirect the error out so we can read it
    psiProcInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True                       'Redirect the standard out so we can read it
    psiProcInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

[bit that changes]
myProcess.Start()
ffreader = myProcess.StandardError
Do
    Try
        If Not myProcess.HasExited Then
            'Debug.WriteLine(ffreader.ReadLine)
        End If
    Catch
        If Not myProcess.HasExited Then
            MsgBox("Something went wrong")
        End If
    End Try
Loop Until myProcess.HasExited
MsgBox("done")
```

I then found another example that just called the executable and then continued when it was done - as below:

```
[same initialisation]
Debug.WriteLine("Starting...")
myProcess.Start()
strOutput = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd
myProcess.WaitForExit()
myProcess.Close()

Debug.Write(strOutput)
MsgBox("done")
```

The second approach worked perfectly... What's different about the "exit state" that `Process.HasExited` and `Process.WaitForExit` look for?

Comment: Process.HasExited is just a function that returns a boolean value that your code can test while it is doing other things. Process.WaitForExit is a method that suspends execution on the thread that is was called from until the Process has exited.

Comment: Ok, so why is WaitForExit working as intended, but for the same input and executable HasExited never becomes True.